# Filter multi index pivot table based on value count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

My code for the pivot table is:

```
games_df.pivot_table(index=['Name', 'Platform'], values='total_sale', aggfunc='sum')
```

I get the following pivot table:

```
                                                        total_sale
Name                                          Platform            
 beyblade burst                               3DS             0.03
 fire emblem fates                            3DS             1.67
 frozen: olaf's quest                         3DS             0.59
                                              DS              0.51
 haikyu!! cross team match!                   3DS             0.04
...                                                            ...
zumba fitness: world party                    Wii             0.23
                                              XOne            0.24
zwei!!                                        PSP             0.02
zyuden sentai kyoryuger: game de gaburincho!! 3DS             0.05
¡shin chan flipa en colores!                  DS              0.14
```

I want to compare the total_sale of the same game between different platforms and this is why I want to filter out games that only have one value under the Platform column. I want to be left out with df that have games that were released on more then one platform. Is it possible to do such filtering when calling pivot_table?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it:

```
pivot=games_df.pivot_table(index=['Name', 'Platform'], values='total_sale', aggfunc='sum')

pivot.groupby('Name').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)

                                     total_sale
Name                       Platform            
 frozen: olaf's quest      3DS             0.59
                           DS              0.51
007: quantum of solace     DS              0.13
                           PC              0.02
                           PS2             0.43
...                                         ...
zumba fitness              X360            2.37
zumba fitness core         Wii             0.07
                           X360            0.05
zumba fitness: world party Wii             0.23
                           XOne            0.24
```

Comment: Nice solution. However, please keep in mind that `len` also counts rows with invalid/missing values (`<NA>` or `NaN`). If you don't want that, you can use the `count` method: `df.groupby('Name').filter(lambda x: x['total_sale'].count() > 1)`.